# Shorting Realtime Firebase endless scrolling data in descending order

Tags: java, android, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My good Evening comes with new a new problem of "Endless Scrolling of firebase realtime database not Giving Proper Results".Actually, I have a database that stores information of users(like=age, diamond, name, etc).
JSON like this ways:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmFxe.png

I can't load all of them in recycler view adapter at once so I decided to use endless scrolling that load data in recycler adapter when we scroll down to the end. Also a short them by decreasing order of diamonds Hence the Users more diamonds come first.

////////////////////////////////Main class//////////////////////////////////

```
public class XYZ extends Frag
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    final List<Upload>  mUpload = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD = 6;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String user_child;

    String LastKey="!";
    int count_read=0;

    private static final int Total_load_chat =7;
    public int Current_paged=1;
    private String pre_key="";
    private String last_key="";
    private int item_no=0;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String user_child = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),mUpload);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int Current_paged) {
                item_no = 0;
                loadMoreData();
            }
        });
        loadData();


        return view;

    }


private void loadData() {

                    DatabaseReference readDatabase=  mDatabase.child("xyz");
                    final Query Shorted =readDatabase
                                 .orderByChild("diamond")
                                 .limitToLast(Total_load_chat*Current_paged);
                    Shorted.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No more  Users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Current_paged--;
                        }

                        Upload  upload = dataSnapshot.getValue( Upload.class);
                            upload.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                            item_no++;
                            if(item_no==1){
                                String messagekey= dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                last_key= messagekey;
                                pre_key= messagekey;

                            }}}});
    }


    private void loadMoreData(){
        DatabaseReference readDatabase=  mDatabase.child("xyz");
        final Query Shorted =readDatabase.orderByChild("diamond").endAt(last_key).limitToLast(5);
                Shorted.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot mdataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        if(!mdataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No more  Users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Current_paged--;
                        }

                 Upload  upload = mdataSnapshot.getValue( Upload.class);
                            upload.setKey(mdataSnapshot.getKey());
                            String messagekey= mdataSnapshot.getKey();

                        if(item_no==0){
                            last_key= messagekey;
                        }
                        if(!pre_key.equals(messagekey)){
                            upload.setKey(mdataSnapshot.getKey());
                            mUpload.add(item_no++,upload);
                        }else{
                            pre_key=last_key;
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(RecyclerView.GONE);
                    }
             }
```

//////////////////////////////Endless scrolling class///////////////////////

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
  public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

  private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
  private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
  private int visibleThreshold = 0; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
  int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

  private int Current_paged = 1;

  private LinearLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager;

  public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager LinearLayoutManager) {
    this.mGridLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
      if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
      }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
      // End has been reached

        Current_paged++;

      onLoadMore(Current_paged);

      loading = true;
    }
  }

  public abstract void onLoadMore(int Current_paged);
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Finally expecting correct descending order(diamond decrease) but I reality I got the Totaly different results as follow:

1. It is a never-ending scrolling list.
2. It is repeating the data again and again on scrolling down.
3. Order also not correct after the first time

Comment: I'm pretty sure Firebase provides a list adapter over it's queries without the need for you to roll your own adapter logic.

Comment: Sorry, But firebase provides the only query by a child, Nothing more. There is some problem in storing the last key. As it loads new data from last key.

Comment: Does that mean [this FirebaseListAdapter class](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html) doesn't fit your needs, or you just didn't know? If former, what is wrong with it?

Comment: The firebase list adapter class will never change my answer as a firebase list is an easy method. But my problem is not in the adapter .

Comment: My problem is how to about endless scrolling shorting! V O T E  so this question got the answer!

Comment: Just to clarify for myself: "shorting" and "sorting" is the same thing, or are we talking about different things? Because you already have the `orderByChild` that sorts your query result.

Comment: that's the same thing!  here is some logical problem:
int count_read=0; private static final int Total_load_chat =7;   public int Current_paged=1;                                                                                              private int item_no=0; if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){ Current_paged--;}
 Upload  upload = dataSnapshot.getValue( Upload.class);
 upload.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
 item_no++;
 if(item_no==1){
 String messagekey= dataSnapshot.getKey();
 last_key= messagekey;
pre_key= messagekey;
}}

Comment: I see no logical problem in your code.

Comment: there is some problem in taking the last key and previous key!

Comment: Thank you for deleting your previous question - unfortunately, it was off-topic. However, I would discourage you from making rollbacks on questions - my change _was_ a good edit. While you are new to Stack Overflow, it is worth seeing how everything works. Good luck!